# ¿como agregar un mensaje en un jTextPane sin que se borren los mensajes anteriores?

Tags: java

se muestran los mensajes antes guardados en la base de datos pero cuando envío uno se me borra toda la conversación, estoy usando setText()
porque el append() no lo acepta el jtextpane.

entonces lo que necesito es una funcion como la que hace append() en jtextarea.. pero en jtextpane

```
public void enviarMensajes() {
        try {
            try (Socket misocket = new Socket("192.168.250.211", 9000)) {
                paqueteEnvio datos = new paqueteEnvio();
                if (listaCordinadorAs.getSelectedValue().equals("TODOS")) {
                    datos.setCamp("0");
                } else {

                    datos.setCamp(String.valueOf(getIDCamp(listaCordinadorAs.getSelectedValue())));
                }
                datos.setMensaje(txtEscribeAsesor.getText());
                datos.setNombre(nombre);
                datos.setIp("0");
                ObjectOutputStream paqueteDatos = new ObjectOutputStream(misocket.getOutputStream());
                paqueteDatos.writeObject(datos);
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                Date dat = new Date();
                String date = dateFormat.format(dat);

                txpConversacionAsesor.setText(datos.getNombre()+": \n "+datos.getMensaje()+"\n"+date+"\n\n");
                misocket.close();
            }
            txtEscribeAsesor.setText("");

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        //sendNotifi();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No haría falta otro método si **previamente obtiene el texto anterior** con la función `getText()`, **luego lo concatena** con su otro texto y, finalmente **muestra el nuevo texto en pantalla**.

Básicamente sería algo así:

```
String text_actual = textPane.getText(); // textPane es nuestro JTextPane()
String text_nuevo = "Este es mi texto nuevo";
textPane.setText(text_actual + " " + text_nuevo);
```

Si aún así requiere de una función, tal vez podríamos crear algo como esto:

```
public void setNewText(JTextPane textPane, String newText) {
    String text_actual = textPane.getText();
    textPane.setText(text_actual + " " + newText);
}
```

Y luego mostramos el mensaje:

```
String text_nuevo = "Este es mi texto nuevo"; 
setNewText(textPane, text_nuevo); // textPane es nuestro JTextPane()
```